# detect if video.load is successful or not - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

How can I know if load of a song is successfull?
something like:

```
video.load({
        success : function() {
            alert("loading successful");
        },
        failure : function() {
            alert("loading not successful");
        } 
    });
```

I have list of songs to play, and if suddenly there is a problem with internet connection and next video can't be played, I want to play the next song that already have been laoded..

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on what you call a success when loading a video. Being able to fully play the video is one thing and just loading the metadata is another, and there are events for each. Same with failure: Would you consider a very long period of buffering an error?

Please refer to the list of events fired by HTMLMediaElement here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

As for listening to these events, this code might be helpful:

```
var v = document.createElement("VIDEO");

v.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
    console.log("Error while loading the video");
});

v.addEventListener("loadeddata", function () {
    console.log("Video has started loading successfully!");
});

v.src = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4";
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [error property](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_error.asp) of the html5 video tag (but this seems to be IE only at this time).
Another approach (for FireFox) is [HTML 5 Video Error handling in  Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4 / Thunderbird 3.3 / SeaMonkey 2.1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video#Error_handling).

> To detect that all child  elements have failed to load, check the value of the media element's networkState attribute. If this is HTMLMediaElement.NETWORK_NO_SOURCE, you know that all the sources failed to load.

Hope this helps!